# How deploy a project loopback 4 to vps

Tags: node.js, loopback, loopback4

I have a project bill by loopback 4 use bitbucket to save source. Now I want to deploy project on vps.
My vps use OS centos 8. I installed Node, MongoDB, ...

I also install `pm2` and config `nginx`.

I tried copy file `dist` from local to server and use command `pm2 start index.js`. But it not working.

I check pm2 error and see log:

```
0|index    |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
0|index    |     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
0|index    |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
0|index    |     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
0|index    | { Error: Cannot find module '@loopback/boot'
0|index    |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
0|index    |     at Module.Hook._require.Module.require (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/require-in-the-middle/index.js:51:29)
0|index    |     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
0|index    |     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/nginx/html/src/application.ts:1:1)
0|index    |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
0|index    |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
0|index    |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
0|index    |     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
0|index    |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
0|index    |     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
```

Please help step to deploy and exist project to server vps.

Comment: tried building on server?

Comment: I don't understand. What do you meaning?

Comment: did you installed all node modules correctly? copy `package.json` and run `npm i`

Comment: Thank for you reply. I deploy success.

Comment: so, please add the solution also. Someone will find it useful

Comment: I follow this tutorial https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/deploying-with-pm2-and-nginx.html